# How to pull data from KML/XML?

Tags: php, ruby, xml, nokogiri, hpricot

I have some data I converted to XML from a KML file and I was curious how to use PHP or Ruby to get back things like the neighborhood names and coordinates. I know when they have a tag around them like so.

```
<cities>
  <neighborhood>Gotham</neighborhood>
</cities>
```

but the data is unfortunately formatted as:

```
<SimpleData name="neighborhd">Colgate Center</SimpleData>
```

instead of

```
<neighborhd>Colgate Center</neighborhd>
```

This is the KML source:

How can I use PHP or Ruby to pull data from something like this? I installed some Ruby gems for parsing XML data but XML is just something I haven't worked with much.

Comment: Your sample KML isn't correct. Please edit your question and replace it with some that actually closes the tags. Nokogiri is returning entries in `errors` after parsing and is having to fix up your XML by adding `</ExtendedData></Placemark></Folder></Folder></Document></kml>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is invalid, but Nokogiri will attempt to fix it up.

Here's how to check for invalid XML/XHTML/HTML and how to rewrite the section you want.

Here's the setup:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri.XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <Document>
    <Schema name="Sample_Neighborhoods_Samples" id="Sample_Neighborhoods_Samples">
      <SimpleField type="int" name="nid"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="neighborhd"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="place"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="placecode"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="nbr_type"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="po_name"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="metro"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="country"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="state"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="statefips"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="county"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="countyfips"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="mcd"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="mcdfips"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="cbsa"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="cbsacode"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="cbsatype"/>
      <SimpleField type="double" name="cenlat"/>
      <SimpleField type="double" name="cenlon"/>
      <SimpleField type="int" name="color"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="ncs_code"/>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="release"/>
    </Schema>
    <Style id="KMLSTYLER_6">
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>1.0</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
      <LineStyle>
        <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <color>7f4080ff</color>
        <colorMode>random</colorMode>
      </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <name>Sample_Neighborhoods_NYC</name>
    <visibility>1</visibility>
    <Folder id="kml_ft_Sample_Neighborhoods_Samples">
      <name>Sample_Neighborhoods_Samples</name>
      <Folder id="kml_ft_Sample_Neighborhoods_Samples_Sample_Neighborhoods_NYC">
        <name>Sample_Neighborhoods_NYC</name>
        <Placemark id="kml_1">
          <name>Colgate Center</name>
          <Snippet> </Snippet>
          <styleUrl>#KMLSTYLER_6</styleUrl>
          <ExtendedData>
            <SchemaData schemaUrl="#Sample_Neighborhoods_Samples">
              <SimpleData name="nid">7086</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="neighborhd">Colgate Center</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="place">Jersey City</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="placecode">36000</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="nbr_type">S</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="po_name">JERSEY CITY</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="metro">New York City, NY</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="country">USA</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="state">NJ</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="statefips">34</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="county">Hudson</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="countyfips">34017</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="mcd">Jersey City</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="mcdfips">36000</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="cbsa">New York-Northern New Jersey-Long Island, NY-NJ-PA</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="cbsacode">35620</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="cbsatype">Metro</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="cenlat">40.7145135000001</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="cenlon">-74.0343385</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="color">1</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="ncs_code">40910000</SimpleData>
              <SimpleData name="release">1.12.2</SimpleData>
            </SchemaData>
          </ExtendedData>
          <Polygon>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
              <LinearRing>
                <coordinates>-74.036628,40.712211,0 -74.0357779999999,40.7120810000001,0                     -74.035535,40.7122010000001,0 -74.0348299999999,40.71209,0 -74.034903,40.711804,0 -74.033761,40.7116560000001,0 -74.0334089999999,40.7121090000001,0 -74.032996,40.7141330000001,0 -74.0331899999999,40.7141790000001,0 -74.032656,40.7162500000001,0 -74.032231,40.716194,0 -74.032049,40.716908,0 -74.033871,40.7170370000001,0 -74.035629,40.7173710000001,0 -74.035669,40.7171650000001,0 -74.036009,40.715335,0 -74.036325,40.713625,0 -74.036482,40.7123580000001,0 -74.036628,40.712211,0 </coordinates>
              </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
          </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark id="kml_2">
          <name>Colgate Center</name>
          <Snippet> </Snippet>
          <ExtendedData>
EOT
```

Here's how to see if there are errors. Any time `errors` is not empty you have a problem.

```
puts doc.errors
```

Here's one way to find the `SimpleData` nodes throughout a document. I prefer to use CSS accessors over XPath for readability reasons. Sometimes XPath is better because it allows better granularity when searching. You need to learn them both.

```
doc.search('ExtendedData SimpleData').each do |simple_data|
  node_name = simple_data['name']
  puts "<%s>%s</%s>" % [node_name, simple_data.text.strip, node_name]
end
```

Here's the output after running:

```
Premature end of data in tag ExtendedData line 87
Premature end of data in tag Placemark line 84
Premature end of data in tag Folder line 44
Premature end of data in tag Folder line 42
Premature end of data in tag Document line 3
Premature end of data in tag kml line 2
<nid>7086</nid>
<neighborhd>Colgate Center</neighborhd>
<place>Jersey City</place>
<placecode>36000</placecode>
<nbr_type>S</nbr_type>
<po_name>JERSEY CITY</po_name>
<metro>New York City, NY</metro>
<country>USA</country>
<state>NJ</state>
<statefips>34</statefips>
<county>Hudson</county>
<countyfips>34017</countyfips>
<mcd>Jersey City</mcd>
<mcdfips>36000</mcdfips>
<cbsa>New York-Northern New Jersey-Long Island, NY-NJ-PA</cbsa>
<cbsacode>35620</cbsacode>
<cbsatype>Metro</cbsatype>
<cenlat>40.7145135000001</cenlat>
<cenlon>-74.0343385</cenlon>
<color>1</color>
<ncs_code>40910000</ncs_code>
<release>1.12.2</release>
```

I'm not trying to modify the DOM, but it's easy to do:

```
doc.search('ExtendedData SimpleData').each do |simple_data|
  node_name = simple_data['name']
  simple_data.replace("<%s>%s</%s>" % [node_name, simple_data.text.strip, node_name])
end

puts doc.to_xml
```

After running this is the affected section:

```
<ExtendedData>
  <SchemaData schemaUrl="#Sample_Neighborhoods_Samples">
    <nid>7086</nid>
    <neighborhd>Colgate Center</neighborhd>
    <place>Jersey City</place>
    <placecode>36000</placecode>
    <nbr_type>S</nbr_type>
    <po_name>JERSEY CITY</po_name>
    <metro>New York City, NY</metro>
    <country>USA</country>
    <state>NJ</state>
    <statefips>34</statefips>
    <county>Hudson</county>
    <countyfips>34017</countyfips>
    <mcd>Jersey City</mcd>
    <mcdfips>36000</mcdfips>
    <cbsa>New York-Northern New Jersey-Long Island, NY-NJ-PA</cbsa>
    <cbsacode>35620</cbsacode>
    <cbsatype>Metro</cbsatype>
    <cenlat>40.7145135000001</cenlat>
    <cenlon>-74.0343385</cenlon>
    <color>1</color>
    <ncs_code>40910000</ncs_code>
    <release>1.12.2</release>
  </SchemaData>
</ExtendedData>
```

Comment: awesome, i got everything working, i was just curious once i put it in a loop, where can i put the counter so that it goes through the progression and returns all of the ones in the xml, so far i can only return the first in the list

Comment: What counter? It will find all `SimpleData` tags inside a `ExtendedData` tag. If you have multiple `ExtendedData` tags it will process those blocks too.

Comment: I mean after i have fixed it. im now parsing through it, but doing this im only getting the first neighborhood returned. Also with the origional code it also removed the coordinates. (doc/'start').each do|st|
nh = (st/'neighborhd').inner_html
metro = (st/'state').inner_html
puts "#{nh}"
puts "#{metro}"
end

Comment: I can't tell what your original code did because you didn't let us see it. Add a summarized version of it to the question, or provide an accurate sample of what your output should look like. Also, you're only going to get one neighborhood because your sample only shows one. Show code and a more comprehensive sample of your KML and I can help more. As is, I'm flying blind because you haven't given me anything else to work with.

Comment: Sorry I just realized that. Since I have got over the first hurdle I will probably try to reasearch and solve it myself, or post it as another question since it's starting to differ from the origional question. But thanks, you helped a ton.