# How to obtain Element values from a KML by using lmxl

Tags: python, xml, lxml, kml

My problem is very similar to the one found here:

[How to pull data from KML/XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861464/how-to-pull-data-from-kml-xml)

The answer to the above question is to use Nokogiri to fix the format.

I wonder if there is a way to solve a similar problem without fixing the format first.

How can I get the values of the dict, so that I can get 'FM2' and 'FM3' from the Element SimpleData below?

Here is my kml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>Test.kml</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Schema name="test" id="S_test_SSSSSIIIDSDDDDDISSSDSSSDD">
        <SimpleField type="string" name="ID"> <displayName>&lt;b&gt;ID&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
        </SimpleField>
        <SimpleField type="string" name="cname"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;cname&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
        </SimpleField>
    </Schema>
    <Style id="falseColor01">
        <BalloonStyle>
            <text><![CDATA[<table border="0"><tr> 
            <td>b>ID</b>/td>td>$[test/ID]</td></tr>
            <tr><td><b>cname</b></td><td>$[test/cname]</td></tr>
            </table>]]></text>
        </BalloonStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ffffff00</color>
            <width>3</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>ffffff00</color>
            <colorMode>random</colorMode>
            <fill>0</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="falseColor0">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#falseColor00</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#falseColor01</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="falseColor00">
      <BalloonStyle>   
      </BalloonStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ffffff00</color>
            <width>3</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>ffffff00</color>
            <colorMode>random</colorMode>
            <fill>0</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder id="layer 0">
        <name>Test_1</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <Placemark>
            <styleUrl>#falseColor0</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
                <SchemaData schemaUrl="#S_test_SSSSSIIIDSDDDDDISSSDSSSDD">
                    <SimpleData name="ID">FM2</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="cname">FM2</SimpleData>
                </SchemaData>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Polygon>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>150.889999,-32.17281600000001,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <styleUrl>#falseColor0</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
                <SchemaData schemaUrl="#S_test_SSSSSIIIDSDDDDDISSSDSSSDD">
                    <SimpleData name="ID">FM3</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="cname">FM3</SimpleData>
                </SchemaData>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Polygon>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>150.90104,-32.15662800000001,0
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

My aim is to obtain the Element values, i.e. 'FM2' from the Elements 'ID'.

I'm trying to use lxml etree. My code is:

```
tree  = ET.parse(kml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

for Document in root:
    for Folder in Document:
        for Placemark in Folder:
            for ExtendedData in Placemark:
                for SchemaData in ExtendedData:
                    for SimpleData in SchemaData:
                        print(SimpleData.attrib)
```

and the output is:
{'name': 'ID'}
{'name': 'cname'}

How can I get the values of the dict, so that I can get 'FM2' and 'FM3'?

I have spent hours in trying to solve the problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the issues you're having is that when you do `for x in y` you're iterating all children of the current element.

So when you do this:

```py
for Folder in Document:
    ...
```

you're not just iterating over `Folder` elements; you're also iterating over `name`, `open`, `Schema`, `Style`, and `StyleMap` (excluded the namespace for now).

You *could* still get what you want by testing the `name` attribute value and then returning the elements text...

```py
for Document in root:
    for Folder in Document:
        for Placemark in Folder:
            for ExtendedData in Placemark:
                for SchemaData in ExtendedData:
                    for SimpleData in SchemaData:
                        if SimpleData.get("name") == "ID":
                            print(SimpleData.text)
```

but I would not recommend it.

Instead consider using [XPath 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/) with lxml's [`xpath()`](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) function.

This will allow you to directly target the elements you're interested in.

For this example I'm going to use the full path instead of the `//` [abbreviated syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#path-abbrev). I'll also use a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#predicates) to test the attribute value.

At first glance you would think that the XPath to all of the `SimpleData` elements with a `name` attribute value of "ID" would be:

```xml
/kml/Document/Folder/Placemark/ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name='ID']
```

but this is not the case. If you notice there is an `xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"` on the root (`kml`) element. This means that that element and all of its decendant elements are in the default namespace `http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2` (unless declared otherwise on those elements).

To illustrate, if you added a `print(f"In Folder element \"{Folder.tag}\"...")` to your `for Folder in Document` loop, you'd see:

```
In Folder element "{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}name"...
In Folder element "{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}open"...
In Folder element "{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Schema"...
In Folder element "{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Style"...
In Folder element "{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}StyleMap"...
In Folder element "{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Style"...
In Folder element "{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Folder"...
```

There are a few ways to handle [namespaces in lxml](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes), but I prefer to declare them in a dictionary and pass them with the `namespaces` argument.

Here's a full example...

```py
from lxml import etree

ns = {"kml": "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"}

tree = etree.parse("test.kml")

for simple_data in tree.xpath("/kml:kml/kml:Document/kml:Folder/kml:Placemark/kml:ExtendedData/kml:SchemaData/kml:SimpleData[@name='ID']", namespaces=ns):
    print(simple_data.text)
```

Print Output...

```
FM2
FM3
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, your answer is perfect. Just would like to elaborate a little bit. XPath do not have the provision for modifying the KML file? I have gone through the document and could not find any reference to 'append', 'delete', etc.I know I could do it with other modules like pykml.

Comment: XPath itself cannot modify, no. But once an element is selected with the lxml xpath function (or find() or findall()), you can modify using the append, remove, etc. methods of the _Element class. See the methods here: https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html There are also examples throughout the [lxml documentation](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html) but sometimes they're hard to find. There are lots of examples on stackoverflow though.

Comment: I forgot to mention you in my previous comment @Marlin . Please let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: I did spend sometime reading the lxml.etree tutorial, but I guess I still don't fully understand the principle. XPath is pretty straight forward. Just use the path to get down to the Element and get the value with .text. Then, if I need to modify the existing kml, I need to use one of the examples in lxml.etree. However, it doesn't seem to work for me as I cannot work out the namespaces.

Comment: would it be possible that you give me some hint on how to add an Element called <name> with value 'test', right under <Placement> in my example above?

Comment: @Marlin - Can you please create a new question? Also, there aren't any `<Placement>` elements in your example; did you mean Placemark? If so there are 2 of them; how do you want to determine which one to add the new element after?

Comment: Yes, @Daniel, I'll create a new question. I've done more experiment yesterday and learnt quite a lot, but still would like to hear your comments.

Comment: I have created a new post @Daniel. If possible, could you please also explain to me a little bit in details about the concept of namespace? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670854/how-to-update-a-kml-to-include-a-new-element-with-a-value

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I ran into problems with xml validity of your `kml_file`, so I did it this way:

```
import lxml.html
tree  = lxml.html.fromstring(kml_file)
results = tree.xpath("//*[@name = 'ID']")

for i in results:
    if i.text:
        print(i.text)
```

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but the output is:

```
FM2
FM3
```